# kubernetes coredns resolution is failing systematically

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

DNS revolution is systematically failing in my 3 node cluster. I have reviewed the official debugging kubernetes documentation and did not find a resolution. My cluster nodes are CentOS 7 vm's and I'm using a Weave net CNI for Multicast support. Using sniff I was able to get a tcpdump of the DNS messages. What can I do to resolve the DNS failure?

[image]

```
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-22f6v                      1/1     Running   20         23d    10.32.0.2    control.example.com   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-kx9l4                      1/1     Running   20         23d    10.32.0.3    control.example.com   <none>           <none>

kube-system   kube-dns         ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP          23d
```

**Log from coredns pod**

```
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "AAAA IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.example.com. udp 59 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 135 0.025346947s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "A IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.example.com. udp 59 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,rd,ra 135 0.023372789s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "AAAA IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.cluster.local. udp 61 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 154 0.000156607s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "A IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.svc.cluster.local. udp 65 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 158 0.000051891s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "A IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.cluster.local. udp 61 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 154 0.000037125s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "A IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.example.com. udp 59 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd,ra 135 0.000041387s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "AAAA IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.default.svc.cluster.local. udp 73 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 166 0.000068773s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "AAAA IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.svc.cluster.local. udp 65 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 158 0.000037855s
[INFO] 10.44.0.4:50257 - 14336 "AAAA IN nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.example.com. udp 59 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd,ra 135 0.000036585s
```

Comment: when you create a pod and curl a service, what's the behavior?

Comment: i can curl to pods and get back a success

Comment: not a pod, if you mean you curled the IP address of the pod directly. I mean if you curl a service. For example `curl nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: i have curl via a nodeport but not the fqdn

Comment: wait a minute. This service is wrong. you are missing the namespace. It should have been `nmos-registry-67795b97d-jfgsz.NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local`

Comment: well, then create a simple pod, with busybox, for example, and curl the service.

Comment: the objects are all in the nmos-dev namespace. i’ll try curling to the fqdn.

Comment: ➜  examples kubectl -n nmos-dev exec dns-pod -it -- sh
/ # wget -O- nmos-registry.nmos-dev.svc.cluster.local
Connecting to nmos-registry.nmos-dev.svc.cluster.local (10.109.255.226:80)

Comment: Is this problem occurs at all nodes? Or it's the same situation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335802/dns-resolve-problem-in-kubernetes-cluster), if it works on any node could you add kube-proxy logs from working and not working node?

Comment: it seems that it does resolve now?