# Kubernetes - DNS/Core DNS Issue - Public Domains are Not Resolving

Tags: kubernetes, dns

I've a kubernetes setup as mentioned below, but my DNS resolution is broken.

Here my POD

```
ubuntu@mylabs-u20:~/apps$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
dnsutils   1/1     Running   0          49m   10.1.201.8   mylabs-u20   <none>           <none>
ubuntu@mylabs-u20:~/apps$
```

Here is /etc/resolv.conf inside POD

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local cloudflare.com
nameserver 10.152.183.10
options ndots:5
/ #
/ #
```

**DNS Lookup Fails** when it was not an FQDN (Ends without DOT)

```
/ # nslookup example.com
Server:         10.152.183.10
Address:        10.152.183.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find example.com.cloudflare.com: No answer
/ #
```

**DNS Lookup Works FINE** when I enter FQDN (Ends with DOT)

```
/ # nslookup example.com.
Server:         10.152.183.10
Address:        10.152.183.10#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
Name:   example.com
Address: 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946

/ #
```

If I remove "cloudflare.com" (I have another domain in real) from /etc/resolv.conf, resolution woks fine too.

Here is the CoreDNS logs

**1. When it is Working** (removed cloudflare.com from the /etc/resolved.conf)

```
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:46058 - 15787 "A IN example.com.default.svc.cluster.local. udp 55 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 148 0.000130316s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:34316 - 9685 "A IN example.com.svc.cluster.local. udp 47 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 140 0.000059917s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:43405 - 60483 "A IN example.com.cluster.local. udp 43 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 136 0.000044215s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:48369 - 57170 "A IN example.com. udp 29 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 56 0.010594123s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:33164 - 33975 "AAAA IN example.com. udp 29 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 68 0.009416379s
```

**2. When it is NOT Working**

```
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:34554 - 25035 "A IN example.com.default.svc.cluster.local. udp 55 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 148 0.000101023s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:38559 - 31524 "A IN example.com.svc.cluster.local. udp 47 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 140 0.0000872s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:50400 - 12732 "A IN example.com.cluster.local. udp 43 false 512" NXDOMAIN qr,aa,rd 136 0.00004631s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:50010 - 42214 "A IN example.com.cloudflare.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 130 0.042365179s
[INFO] 10.1.201.8:50528 - 22014 "AAAA IN example.com.cloudflare.com. udp 44 false 512" NOERROR qr,rd,ra 130 0.040545068s
```

**Note: If I remove "cloudflare.com" from resolved.conf, it just works fine. Also, I can put "ibm.com" etc, works without any issues.**

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks,
Sethu M

Comment: Hello @SethulIT, welcome to StackOverflow, how did you set up the cluster? Does it have anything to do with cloudflare.com? Does the problem only occur when you set dns to cloudflare.com? Any other site works fine?

Comment: I have a domain, which behaves same live cloud flare. And I see there are many. I'm trying to understand what makes a difference when I add a search domain there.

I hope I provided enough information about my cluster. Let me know if more info required.

Comment: I need to know exactly how did you set up your cluster. For example, are you using bare metal cluster or are you using dedicated tool to cluster creation like AWS EKS or GKE. Could you edit your question and provide more information how did you set up you cluster step by step? What network configuration are you using? What did you deploy inside you cluster and how did you configure DNS in your cluster? Look also at the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335802